Surface charge density within a parallel plate capacitor on different voltages
I need a way to vary the surface charge density without changing the electric field. My idea is to use two large conducting parallel plates close to each other in vacuum enclosed in a grounded vessel (the distance to the vessel is much larger than the distance between the plate). By keeping the voltage difference between my two parallel plates constant (lets say 10 V so that we can have the plates for example from -5 to 5, 0 to 10 and 5 to 15), my electric field within the plates will be constant. So we put one plate on $V_0$ and the other on $V_0+10$ always. How will this change the surface charge on the inside of the conducting parallel plates depending on the voltage $V_0$.
Or will this not change the surface charge density within the conducting plate, as the charge density on the inside of the electric field in between the plates will always be the same due to the fixed value of the electric field although the total charge of the plate will grow by increasing potential which will only affect the surface charge density on the outside of the plates. If so, is there a way to change the surface charge density (on the inside of the electric plates) without changing the electric field? Maybe by adding a third plate at a small distance? Or any ideas on a different setup that can create this?

What you wish to do may be a little difficult as the external electric field is equal to the surface charge density divided by the permittivity.

Changing the potentials on the capacitor plates will not change the inside surface charges as long as the potential difference between the plates is constant. However, for a given potential difference (and thus electric field $E$), you can increase the inside surface charge density $\sigma$  on the plates by filling the space between the plates with a dielectric with a relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$ larger than one. This could be accomplished, e.g., by filling the chamber with a dielectric fluid with different values of $\epsilon_r$. The surface charge density is given by $$\sigma= \epsilon_r \epsilon_o E$$
